# Neural Network Not working for 100X100 image

Tags: c++, opencv, neural-network

I have created a neural network that works when implementing XOR gate it gives me the right result, it also work when inputing an image size of 28X28 although I haven't tested it with other images, 28X28 takes in floating point number and works fine. However, whenever I input an image with a size of 100X100 it doesn't seem to work. I have changed the parameters for hidden layer which are 32 nodes 65 nodes and 100 nodes. The case is different if this 100X100 image is only 1 and 0s. Is it that I could be converting the pixel value wrong but if so why is it working for 28X28 image size?

The algorithm that I am using uses on-line learning where the weights are updates per input.

The other thing that I noticed was whenever I input huge number of data such 100X100 images the algorithm seems to be stuck on 0.3~0.1ish mse. Is it that I could be missing something in the algorithm?

The range for which the weights are -0.5,0.5. Initially they are randomised between those numbers.

I have given the net 3 images to work on of shirt each are 100X100.

```
[outputs] mean-squared-error

32 node error after 400 iteration for 100X100 image with floating point input:

> [ 0.841227 0.674843 0.804683 ] 0.283846  
> [ 0.841227 0.674843 0.804683 ] 0.283846  
> [ 0.841227 0.674843 0.804683 ] 0.283846  
> [ 0.841227 0.674843 0.804683 ] 0.283846   
> [ 0.841227 0.674843 0.804683 ] 0.283846   
> [ 0.841227 0.674843 0.804683 ] 0.283846   
> [ 0.841227 0.674843 0.804683 ] 0.283846 

65 nodes:

> [ 0.897245 0.706758 0.877548 ] 0.302012   
> [ 0.897245 0.706757 0.877549 ] 0.302012   
> [ 0.897245 0.706758 0.877548 ] 0.302012   
> [ 0.897245 0.706757 0.877549 ] 0.302012   
> [ 0.897245 0.706758 0.877548 ] 0.302012   
> [ 0.897245 0.706757 0.877549 ] 0.302012   
> [ 0.897245 0.706758 0.877548 ] 0.302012   
> [ 0.897245 0.706757 0.877549 ] 0.302012   


100 node:

> [ 0.942706 0.843137 0.897838 ] 0.307912   
> [ 0.91558 0.671391 0.938428 ] 0.316687   
> [ 0.942706 0.843141 0.897838 ] 0.307912   
> [ 0.91558 0.671393 0.938427 ] 0.316687   
> [ 0.942706 0.843137 0.897838 ] 0.307912   
> [ 0.91558 0.671391 0.938428 ] 0.316687   
> [ 0.942706 0.84314 0.897838 ] 0.307912
```

Did I get stuck in local minima?

The code is here feel free to look [link](https://github.com/sanny1/Backpropagation)!

Comment: what did you try in order to identify the problem?

Comment: if you mean the problem of having 100X100 image then, I changed the same image to 28X28 image which is then changed to single array and used those inputs to test if image of smaller size is working or not.

Comment: The problem as you can see is that the mean squared error isn't changing at all when for XOR inputs and 28X28 images they were giving me >0.001 mse.

Comment: No, I mean what did you do apart from changing the dimensions of the image to understand what are the roots of the problem, not the consequences.

Comment: I can't think of anything, or haven't logged anything else apart from that as I think the problem is either to do with conversion or I simply don't know where to look. I have also changed the number of nodes as people have said online in other forum that images of 100X100 can be solved by 1 hidden layer so I am still trying that. I only have 1 output in the output layer.

Comment: The image is black and white.

Comment: I have used sigmoid function and tan function

Comment: But they don't make much different except that it changes the mse slightly but it is still stuck

Comment: `[ -0.209225 0.988916 0.992888 0.974128 0.28082 ] 0.0246955 
[ -0.342902 0.974406 0.988425 0.924903 0.125666 ] 0.0279604 
[ -0.0432605 0.969988 0.987082 0.908082 0.0326594 ] 0.00249094 
[ 0.032985 0.969508 0.986992 0.90777 -0.0336623 ] 0.00236532 
[ 0.0920719 0.969643 0.986967 0.896137 -0.0811469 ] 0.00538821 
[ 0.107058 0.973686 0.988132 0.910609 -0.083807 ] 0.00546183 
[ 0.0790964 0.978316 0.989559 0.933648 -0.0443132 ] 0.00264035 
[ 0.0272084 0.98167 0.990654 0.950529 0.0125265 ] 0.000753586 `

Comment: Thats for 28X28 images